# Strange behavior is modifying lists

Tags: java

I've been recently writing a method to join some values which I have in some text files and then modify the ones I want. In the method I write, I got "Index out of the array" in the below code:

```
  String[] s = new String[] {"Value1", "Value2",...}
  List<List<String[]>> Temp = new ArrayList();
  for (List<String[]> i : JL) {
        List<String[]> _Temp = new ArrayList();
        for (String[] x: i) {
            for (String y : s) {
                if (x[0].equals(y))
                    _Temp.add(x);
            }
        }
        _Temp.get(10)[0] = "Some Value"; // Index out of the array error (_Temp lenght is 12)
        // _Temp.get(10) has 2 indexes     
       Temp.add(_Temp);         
    }
```

This is while when I removed the `_Temp.get(10)[0] = "Some Value";` and did the below code, it worked:

```
    for (List<String[]> x : Temp) {
        x.get(10)[0] = "Some Value";
    }
```

How does this happen ? both approaches to modify the value are exactly the same.

Demonstration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier to understand the problem if your variables weren't so poorly named. Instead of `Temp`, `_Temp`, `i`, consider `files`, `rows`, `columns`, or whatever they are.

Comment: @Boann: Although you might be right, I understand them very well and they have nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Good for you. But the people trying to help you don't.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow Clearly you don't! You mixed up `_Temp` with the elements of `Temp`.

Comment: @Boann: No, I figured it out, in the first method I replaced `_Temp.get(10)[0] = "Some Value";` with `System.out.ptintln(_Temp.get(10)[0])` and I could see the values. The  '=' operator is doing something bad to the list like a side effect.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow No, it will ***never*** do that. If reading the array element succeeds, then assigning to it will succeed too. The problem is that you've conflated `_Temp` and the elements of `Temp`. Your claim that "both approaches to modify the value are exactly the same" is just wrong. Give your variables non-horrible names and it will be obvious.

Comment: @Boann: It DOES do that, leave me your email I'll send you the sample code to test it. This is totally a Java List issue. BWT: I'm obfuscating my code for a reason I may make it more obscure and that has nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow No, it doesn't do that. It really doesn't. Either `_Temp.get(10)[0]` is a valid index or it isn't. It can't matter whether you're printing it or assigning it. You said that `x.get(10)[0]` works: well that's because it's a completely different list.

Comment: @Boann: check out the photos I added

Comment: @PierreOverFlow When you do `_Temp.get(10)[0] = ""` the first time around, it prevents `x[0].equals(y)` from matching on subsequent iterations of the `for (List<String[]> i : JL)` loop (because it is the same array you are modifying), which means that `_Temp` will be filled fewer elements on subsequent iterations, which will cause the exception.

Comment: @Boann: Yeah I noticed that, but I can't understand why it happens. How could this affect the `x[0].equals(y)`

Comment: Zero indexing. Size 10 means indexes 0-9, so 10 is out of range.

Comment: @JonK: Seriously Jon :D, Boann has pointed out to the problem in his comment.

Comment: @PierreOverFlow Because apparently you have the same arrays in there twice. I have no idea why -- it's your code. And it's an absolute chore for anyone to make sense of it because the variable names are such a vicious impediment to understanding.

Comment: @Boann: The wired thing that the array is not there twice :D, That's what made me post the question, I put everything I knew together, couldn't figure it and I really appreciate your help Boann when I don't understand something I get little angry at myself so sorry if I wrote any impolite comment.

Answer (score 2):

Well ..

- Neither code snippet ensures that there are 10 items in the `_Temp ArrayList`
- The replacement code snippet works on `Temp`, while the failing one works on `_Temp`

Comment: I've checked it by outputting the list size in the console